# Node js - Best practice for authorizating RESTFUL API requests

Tags: node.js, rest

So I am creating a REST API that will do database queries and send data for my android app in node js. However I want to use some kind of authorization when doing these requersts. Which methods could I use to do this stuff? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few option but I would look at [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) token authentication for this. You'd have the user enter something like a username/pass in the android app then send this securely to your server which will return a token of whatever duration you desire. That token is then sent for every api request - usually in the headers.

Google "Node auth jwt token" and you should get some articles such as [this](http://slatepeak.com/guides/building-a-software-as-a-service-saas-startup-pt-2/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [passport](http://passportjs.org/).

It supports many common authentication strategies, including http bearer, google, facebook, etc. You can also define your own strategy. Have a try!